# Forming a python table with tab

Tags: python, python-3.x, tabs

I have one question about Python 3.X. I'm able to create a nice "table" with .format, but the question is whether I'm able to do it with tabs to look similar to this one with formats?

```
file = open("students.csv", "r")
students= []
for i in file:
    i= i.rstrip()
    i_sublist = i.split(",")
    students.append(i_sublist)


print("Content")
print("{0:15} {1:15} {2:15}".format("Name", "Surname", "Grade"))
print("{0:15} {1:15} {2:15}".format("-----", "-------", "---"))
for i in students:
    for j in i:
        print("{0:15}".format(j),"",end="")
    print()
file.close()
```

Comment: Tabs? Why not spaces?

Comment: @CommonSense - it's an exam task (it says something like form a nice table with "TABULATORS"), I've been trying to form it for almost 2 days, but I'm unable to do it, that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: @Malcom98 it will be hard because `tab` is *de facto* 8 character standard. It is not always possible to fill exactly the field of size 15 it depends on the length of 'Name',....

Comment: If you can use spaces, as alternative to `.format` method of `str`, you can look at `.ljust` method. Or write your one padding function which takes into account the actual length of `str`.

Comment: @godaygo Yes, exactly. It's quite impossible to form a nice table with tabs without format, because each name has different length, and it just won't look like a table, right?

Comment: @godaygo I have also seen module "tabulate" sth like ">>>import tabulate from tabulate", but we do not have that module on exam.

Comment: @Malcom You misunderstood my comment, if your answer how to make fields of size 15 only using tabs (for any input) - my answer I don't know. If your question how to produce the same table without using `.format` method - my answer there are plenty ways, and one of them to use `.ljust` string method.

Answer (score 0):

Although I did not fully understand what your task is (especially about tabs), I'll try to show one way to build a similar table without using `.format` method. Suppose the list of students looks as follows:

```
students = [('Arc', 'Circle', 'A'), ('Numan', 'Tuman', 'B'), ('Zeta', 'Beta', 'D'),
            ('Raptor', 'Strange', 'A'), ('Crazy', 'Bear', 'C')]
```

#### Using other method

Then the following function will print the similar table:

```
def context(students):
    preamble = [("Name", "Surname", "Grade"), 
                 ("----", "-------", "-----")]
    message = preamble + students   # join two lists together
    print("Context")
    for line in message:
        print(*(elem.ljust(15) for elem in line))  # left justify each element in sublists
```

From the documentation:

> `S.ljust(width[, fillchar]) -> str`
>   Return S left-justified in a Unicode string of length `width`. Padding is done using the specified `fill` character (default is a space).

#### Your own tabulator

If your task to implement your own *tabulator* it can be done by providing helper function in this way:

```
def tabulator(text, min_field=15):
    tabs_to_append = min_field - len(text)  
    return_string = (text if (tabs_to_append <= 0) else text + " "*tabs_to_append)
    return return_string 

def context_tabulator(students):
    preamble = [("Name", "Surname", "Grade"), 
                 ("----", "-------", "-----")]
    message = preamble + students   # join two lists together
    print("Context")
    for line in message:
        print(*(tabulator(elem, 15) for elem in line))
```

if you invoke it as `context_tabulator(students)` it will produce the following table:

```
Context
Name            Surname         Grade          
----            -------         -----          
Arc             Circle          A              
Numan           Tuman           B              
Zeta            Beta            D              
Raptor          Strange         A     
Crazy           Bear            C
```

It should be noted that all of the above examples only show you general idea, and do not validate or convert the provided input for arguments. Nonetheless, I hope this will help you.